# Pandas dataframe aggregation on dynamic groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Date        Value
2023-05-20  2
2023-05-22  4
2023-05-22  3
2023-05-24  5
```

There may be missing days, and also days having multiple entries.
How do I get a list of *all* days (between lowest and largest given day) cumulating the sum of values "so far", in this example the result should look like:

```
Date        ValueCum
2023-05-20  2
2023-05-21  2
2023-05-22  9
2023-05-23  9
2023-05-24  14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code**

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
out = (df.resample(rule='D', on='Date')['Value'].sum()
         .cumsum()
         .reset_index(name='ValueCum'))
```

out:

```
        Date  ValueCum
0 2023-05-20         2
1 2023-05-21         2
2 2023-05-22         9
3 2023-05-23         9
4 2023-05-24        14
```

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Date': ['2023-05-20', '2023-05-22', '2023-05-22', '2023-05-24'], 
         'Value': [2, 4, 3, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```